# Random Selection from an array in c

Tags: c, command-prompt

Basically, I'm trying to make a card game where 5 random cards are selected from a deck of cards (deck is in the array). So when a card is given to the player its random and then that card can't be given again.

This is all done from one two dimensional array.

Also, this game is fully done in command prompt, so no engines or anything like that.

My question is how can i get random variables from the said array multiple times and be sure the same variable cant be called twice.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes sorry i updated the post there

Comment: Look at _rand()_ and _srand(seed)_ for random number, and perhaps _time()_ to be used as _seed_

Comment: Why two-dimensional array? What's in a[i][j]?

Comment: **1)** use a bitmap(64> 52)  or **2)** set the spots of the used cards to some  sentinel value, such as -1 or **3)** after drawing, check if that card is already in the result set; if so: draw again.

Comment: It is two dimensional because i need to know the suits and the card number, its a card game called 25.

Comment: It can be one-dimentional,since you can enumerate the cards.

Comment: Shuffle the deck array, and treat it like a stack, popping cards off it as they're dealt.

Answer (score 0):

rand() function gives random number. Worth to check its man page